# Any way to force the user to login using the Facebook OAuth dialog?

Tags: php, facebook

I am using the `auth_type` parameter with the OAuth dialog to force the user to relogin as per the [documentation here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-re-auth/).

If the user is not logged into Facebook, he has to enter his username and password, which is good.

However, if the user is logged into Facebook, all it does is show a dialogue with the user's name and asks them to re-enter their password.

This isn't very nice for us, because our app has the feature to connect to multiple Facebook accounts. And to rub salt into our wounds (so to speak :P), the OAuth dialog does not even have a "not you?" link to allow them to switch users.

Our app is built with PHP and uses the [server-side login flow](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-login/).

**Is there anyway to force the user to have to re-enter both his password and email address?** Something like Twitter's [force_login](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/oauth/authorize) is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Use may a`FB.Login` instead of `OAuth`, if you want to force the user to login each time.

Docs: [FB.Login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/)